# Guest with static IP - slow internet connection, random pings

Tags: virtual-machine, dns, ping, bridge, static-ip

I have Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine with static ip and bridged network. Internet connection on host is wireless and most of the time works well, but sometimes it is a little bit slower too, but not much. Guest connection is significantly slower and some pings are low, some are average, some are very high. With NAT host and guest work well. I have set dns server to 8.8.8.8. As you can see almost half of pings are very high, over 1000ms. And it looks totally random, one ping is low, next is high, next low, next high, etc.

Average ping from router to host with guest machine turned off is about few miliseconds. When I turn on virtual machine almost all pings from router to host are above 100ms. Average ping from router to guest is about 600-1200ms.

Here's ping from guest to 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=1098 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=88.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=1235 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=235 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=2305 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=1297 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=54 time=289 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=54 time=41.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=54 time=1357 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=54 time=358 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=54 time=2129 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=54 time=1130 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=54 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=54 time=37.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=15 ttl=54 time=2110 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=16 ttl=54 time=1101 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=17 ttl=54 time=94.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=18 ttl=54 time=35.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=19 ttl=54 time=29.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=20 ttl=54 time=1082 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=21 ttl=54 time=75.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=22 ttl=54 time=2173 ms
```

guest /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.223
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
```

traceroute from guest to 8.8.8.8

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  1034.355 ms  1034.144 ms  1034.345 ms
 2  10.16.0.0 (10.16.0.0)  1034.388 ms  1034.509 ms  1034.575 ms
 3  185.28.16.1 (185.28.16.1)  1034.793 ms  1035.728 ms  1035.701 ms
 4  ip-91.189.249.37.s.net.pl (91.189.249.37)  1038.276 ms  1038.061 ms  1037.881 ms
 5  te2-7.251.ccr01.krk01.atlas.cogentco.com (149.6.74.109)  1034.582 ms  1034.839 ms  1035.011 ms
 6  te2-7.ccr01.brq01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.1)  1035.293 ms  75.936 ms  75.723 ms
 7  te0-4-0-7.ccr21.bts01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.59.149)  18.671 ms  18.613 ms te0-1-0-6.ccr21.bts01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.36.109)  20.575 ms
 8  be2222.ccr21.vie01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.1.50)  21.350 ms be2221.ccr21.vie01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.48.142)  22.401 ms  22.402 ms
 9  be2200.ccr21.muc01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.49.1)  31.606 ms  31.563 ms  31.460 ms
10  be2228.ccr41.fra03.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.49)  33.276 ms  33.278 ms be2229.ccr42.fra03.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.57)  33.165 ms
11  be2184.agr21.fra03.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.48.69)  36.464 ms be2188.agr21.fra03.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.48.113)  34.667 ms  34.651 ms
12  149.6.42.46 (149.6.42.46)  32.953 ms  28.052 ms  27.741 ms
13  216.239.46.121 (216.239.46.121)  28.700 ms  28.506 ms  28.467 ms
14  216.239.49.245 (216.239.49.245)  30.012 ms 209.85.246.189 (209.85.246.189)  32.770 ms 209.85.241.39 (209.85.241.39)  32.751 ms
15  google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  30.771 ms  32.537 ms  30.076 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with router. I have connected ISP to another router and problem is gone. Dynamic IP is assigned and there are no lags.